# Hover on a div, view text

Tags: html, text, hover

I have been making a navigator with only pictures but I also need text, but there was no place to put text. So what I want is, when the user hover an image a new div to be shown with the text.

**Code:**

```
<a href="../profile.php">
  <img src="../img/profile.png" style="border: gray 1px solid; margin-left: 0px; width: 45px;" />
</a>
<a href="../shop.php">
  <img src="../img/shop.png" style="border: gray 1px solid; margin-left: 10px; width: 45px;" />
</a>
<a href="../settings.php">
  <img src="../img/indstillinger.png" style="border: gray 1px solid; margin-left: 10px; width: 45px;" />
</a>
<a href="../casino.php">
  <img src="../img/casino.png" style="border: gray 1px solid; margin-left: 10px; width: 45px;" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [title="my tooltip"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_title.asp) attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is something like this:

```
<a href="../profile.php"><img src="../img/profile.png" title="Here comes hover text" style="border: gray 1px solid; margin-left: 0px; width: 45px;"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Add a `<p>` element after each of your `<img>` tags:

```
<p class="popup">Caption goes here</p>
```

Then with **CSS** `visibility` property you can show/hide the caption:

```
a {
  display:inline-block;
}

img {  
  border: 1px solid #aaa;  
}  

.popup {
  visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

a:hover .popup {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

See an **[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxyLaP)**.